# The Use of s-Genitive

Tags: possessives

I'm writing my essay about corruption (Part II.) and I have already come across two words (one of which is rewritten for political reasons)...

> **MAMESZ**

and

> **police**

...that have to be put into the s-Genitive case. The problem is that these words end in the phoneme /s/ that is the same as that of the s-Genitive.

How should I use the s-Genitive?

> **MAMESZ'** and **police'**

or

> **MAMESZ's** and **police's**

...and how are they pronounced in case they are embellished with an s-Genitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's not a genitive, its a clitic.*

The spelling is certainly "police's", [po'li:siz]. Probably "Mamesz's" [mamesiz] is prefered by most writers, but there is some variation. For example

> Alexis **Sanchez's** struggles reveal Manchester United's main problem in attack under Jose Mourinho [source](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/manchester-united-sevilla-alexis-sanchez-champions-league-a8255536.html)

For the police, consider rewording using "of": Instead of saying "The police's role has changed." say "The role of the police has changed".

Comment: Isn't the pronunciation [mamesiz]? In Hungarian MAMESZ is pronounced as [mames]. Or does that clitic change the pronunciation?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Hungarian! I'll edit

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to criticise you, I just wondered if that was so. Thank you for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single rule. Some writers add a possessive apostrophe after a final 'z': Mamesz' Sanchez' Diaz', other add an 's' as well. Mamesz's Sanchez's Diaz's. The final 'z' consonant is not sounded identically with a final 's' in the second two examples; I do not know how Mamesz is pronounced alone, but I would say Sanchezes car, Diazes house. I would probably guess at saying 'Mamezes'